# Off grid solar PV performance analysis

Tags: solar-energy, power-meter, power-measurement

I need to compare a single axis solar PV tracker system with a fixed tilt solar PV system for how much power produced in 1 day or 1 week or 1 month. Both systems will be off grid. What kind of load do i need to use  to measure produced power off grid and without using inverter?

Comment: *Is there any way to measure produced power off grid and without using inverter?* <-- yes there is; it's volts x amps and, if you want energy, it's volts x amps x time. Dozens of electronics solutions to this.

Comment: If you just want to compare the two, you can do this with a calculation. There are online tools for the very purpose where you enter location and, fixed angle and which axis is tracked.

Comment: @Andyaka İ'm newbie to this topic i think i asked wrong question. i want to know what kind of load connect to panels for measure momentary and long term produced power.

Comment: You don't connect a specific load; you measure the power consumed by your loads. Maybe you need to think about this a bit more. Asking questions is sometimes a lot harder than answering them.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you may be missing that a typical "load" on a solar panel is a Maximum Power Point Tracker (MPPT), which adjusts itself dynamically to optimise (volts x amps). Simply stuffing a resistor across the panels won't give a useful result.

Comment: I'm not suggesting anything like that @SimonB

Comment: You sound as though you just want to measure the benefit of the tracker vs fixed.  Or do you actually want to use the energy?